# create a dynamic insert query in python to save data in mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a table in mysql and i am inserting data in it from a python client.

I am using a insert query to insert data into the table

code

```
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Data
                          (`deviceID`,`date`,`timestamp`,`counter`,`rssi`,
                            `CO2 Sensor Value`,
                            `Supply DPT`,
                            `block`,
                            `floor`) 
                             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
```

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='minniedb',user='',
                                    password='',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
cursor = connection.cursor()

"""
 create 'insert_tuple' based on some api calls
"""
cursor.execute(sql_insert_query,insert_tuple)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
print('inserted in db')
```

This works fine when everything is static. I have a case when the number of columns in my table is around 60-70 and the parameters I get from api is a subset of columns(around 10-15) and these parameters can change every time. The api returns the column name and the value.
Sample return from api can be of form

```
{
    'deviceID':20,
    'counter' :61,
    'block'   :'A'

}
```

or it can be

```
{
   'deviceID'        :25,
   'CO2 Sensor Value':600,
   'floor'           : 5

}
```

How do i write a query in such case to insert whatever data i received from api in the respective columns and have others as null.

Comment: Could you add an example of the API output to you question, just for reference.

Comment: sure, will do that

Comment: Using column names from a 3rd party is dangerous. The quoting mechanism in `.execute()` does not work on them and injection code could be included. It would be best if you always store all values with the empty onces as `None`. Or at least incorporate a check of the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
sensor_data = {
    'deviceID':20,
    'counter' :61,
    'block'   :'A'

} 
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Data {} VALUES {}""".format(tuple(sensor_data.keys()), tuple(sensor_data.values()))
```

P.S: For sensor data I'll suggest using google Firebase :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, columns in my db are of type `varchar` and `float` . I get an error while trying to save in db. I get an error `Failed inserting record into python_users table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_Temp', 'CH_1_Motor_Current_limit_SP', 'CH_1_Leaving_C'` . these are the columns of float type